# loop from different prices select match value price

Tags: php

I have different discount prices in array, when I run the loop of this array, I put the value to condition when price is greater than or equal to 7 USD discount 20% will be applied.

When price less than 30 USD discount must be applied 20%. When price is greater than or equal to 30 USD discount must be applied 23%.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [title] => Get 20% off on discount with 7 USD or above
        [price] => 7
        [discount] => 20%
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 41
        [title] => Get 23% discount with 30 USD or above
        [price] => 30
        [discount] => 23%
    )
)
```

I tried the loop like:

```
$isAvailable = false;
$price = 25;
foreach($discount_results as $discount_result){

    if($price >= $discount_result['price'] && $price < $discount_result['price']){
        $isAvailable = true;

        $data[] = [
            'id' =>     $discount_result['id'],
            'price' =>     $discount_result['price'],
            'isAvailable' => $isAvailable
        ];
    }
}
```

I want result look like:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [price] => 7
        [isAvailable] => 1
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 41
        [price] => 30
        [isAvailable] => 0
    )
)
```

Comment: what is the idea of `$isAvailable` flag?

Comment: when condition is matched, for example now price is `$price = 25`, he must be return `true` on `20%` discount. When price upto 30, discount `23%` is `true`

Comment: What exactly is stopping you checking those conditions?

Comment: why you in the same condition use "more" "equal" and "less"? `if($price >= $discount_result['price'] && $price < $discount_result['price']){
        $isAvailable = true;
    }` If you need that discount  should be less use just: `if($price >= $discount_result['price']){
        $isAvailable = true;
    }`

Comment: Can you explain your problem? What errors and other problem you are getting?

Comment: @B001ᛦ the problem is that when I run the condition when price upto `7 USD` both return true, but I want if price `7 USD` or less than `30 USD` its must be applied `1st discount 20%`. When price is greater than or equal to `30 USD` than applied `2nd discount 23%`, I show example in array.

Comment: _When price is greater than or equal to 30 USD than ..._ Okay, now you need your `If`

Comment: @MrTom Why not just return the discount percentage from your loop? Something like https://3v4l.org/ec3O8

Comment: @BrettGregson I show example please check this link [https://3v4l.org/QnSpJ](https://3v4l.org/QnSpJ). Its both is `true`, but I require when price is `30 USD` return array which have `30 USD` price is true and `7 USD` will be `false`

Comment: @MrTom a bit ugly but how about https://3v4l.org/S2hWX